# ¿Cómo resolver el siguiente error en flutter?

Tags: flutter, cmd

Buen día Comunidad

Instalé flutter, cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando en cmd "flutter doctor", la consola me muestra el siguiente error

Necesito un consejo, no sé cómo averiguarlo.

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tu flutterSdk que descargaste este cprrupto, puedes intentar borrar el que tienes ahora e instalar de nuevo y agregar el path, en  variable de entorno.
Espero que te ayude en algo :)